# Upsert and Multi flag in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am working on pymongo and this is my document:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("51211b57f07ddaa377000000"),
   "assignments": {
     "0": {
       "0": {
         "_id": ObjectId("5120dd7400a4453d58a0d0ec") 
      },
       "1": {
         "_id": ObjectId("5120dd8e00a4453d58a0d0ed") 
      },
       "2": {
         "_id": ObjectId("5120ddad00a4453d58a0d0ee") 
      } 
    } 
  },
   "password": "my_passwd",
   "username": "john" 
}
```

I would like to unset the "assignment" property of all such docs.
I was able to achieve this on the mongo shell by doing:

```
db.users.update({}, {$unset: {"assignments": 1}}, false, true)
```

i.e., I passed the upsert and multi flag as the last two parameters to the update function function on users collection.
However I did this with pymongo:

```
db.users.update({}, {"$unset": {"assignments": 1}}, False, True)
```

But the python interpreter threw an error as follows:

```
File "notes/assignment.py", line 34, in <module>
    db.users.update({}, {"$unset": {"assignments": 1}}, False, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 481, in update
    check_keys, self.__uuid_subtype), safe)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 852, in _send_message
    rv = self.__check_response_to_last_error(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 795, in __check_response_to_last_error
    raise OperationFailure(details["err"], details["code"])
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Modifiers and non-modifiers cannot be mixed
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14443478/remove-subfields-from-mongodb-document maybe you'll find something familiar

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem is that the two flags you are passing in aren't `upsert` and `multi`. Based on the documentation of PyMongo's `Collection.update` (found [here](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update)), it looks like you might be passing in values for the `upsert` and `manipulate` options, although I am not certain.

All you have to do to solve this is use one of Python's most awesome features: named arguments. By specifying which options you are passing to `update`, you add clarity to your code in addition to making sure accidents like this don't happen.

In this case, we want to pass the options `upsert=False` and `multi=True`.

```
db.users.update({}, { "$unset": { "assignments": 1 } }, upsert=False, multi=True)
```